# Elementary proofs of $\pi_k(S^n)=0$ for $1\leq k<n$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Is there an elementary proof of the triviality of the first homotopy groups of spheres (i.e. the statement that for $1\leq k<n,\;\pi_k(S^n)=0$)? By elementary I mean without using the tool of cellular approximation or Hurewicz theorem.

(This question is a follow up to the [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/774932/why-are-the-fundamental-groups-pi-1s3-and-pi-1s2-trivial) asking for an elementary proof in the case $k=1$ (which is needed to apply the Hurewicz theorem anyways), so I'm only interested in the case $k>1$)

Comment: Any proof needs to confront the horror of space-filling curves in some way. In some sense this is just a technical artifact of working with topological spaces as a model for homotopy theory though.

Comment: If you want a proof along the lines of Seifert -van Kampen theorem then they will all be much less elementary than the approximation technique or Hurewicz theorem. Google "van Kampen theorem for higher homotopy groups" to find some references.

Answer (score 6):

Given a continuous function $f:S^k \to S^n$, find a continuously differentiable function $g:S^k \to S^n$ so that $|g(x) - f(x)| \le 1/10$.  Show that $f$ and $g$ are homotopic.  Also show that $g$ cannot be onto (i.e. there are no space filling continuously differentiable maps).  Use a point in $S^n \setminus g(S^k)$ to create the homotopy to the constant map.